# Width of item in column gets altered when new item is added to the list, CSS NodeJS

Tags: html, css, node.js, width, overflow

So I am trying to create a project gallery with a list of different projects, the projects are added via NodeJS. And when I built the thumbnail for the project gallery I had 2 items for the thumbnail as such:

[image]

And I want it so that any new projects added go into the overflow and you are able to scroll along with the projects then. But instead, this is what happens when I add a new project:
[image]

Note this was built from mobile first (320px).
Here is my code, the `html-file`:

```
<!--Thumbnail images--> 
            <div class="section-projects-thumbnail-mtitle">Other Projects</div>
            
            <div class="section-projects-thumbnail-row">
                <% projectdetails.forEach(item => { %> 
                    <div class="section-projects-thumbnail-col" >
                        <img class="section-projects-thumbnail-img cursor" data-id="<%=item.prjID %>" src="data:<%=item.img.contentType%>;base64,<%=item.img.data.toString('base64')%>" onclick="currentSlide(this)">
                        <div class="section-projects-thumbnail-title-container"><h3 class="section-projects-thumbnail-title"><%= item.projectName %></h3></div>
                        <h4 class="section-projects-thumbnail-date"><%= item.projectDate %></h4>
                    </div> 
                <% }) %> 
            </div>
```

The `.css` file:

```
.section-projects-thumbnail-mtitle {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1rem;
    position: absolute;
    top: 91%;
    color: #01c2b1;
    letter-spacing: 0.07rem;
}

.section-projects-thumbnail-row{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: absolute;
    top: 99%;
    height: 35%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.section-projects-thumbnail-row::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}

/* Six columns side by side */
.section-projects-thumbnail-col {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    height: 105%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-right: 3%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* Add a transparency effect for thumnbail images */
.section-projects-thumbnail-img {
    display: block;
    width: 90%;
    height: 60%;
    opacity: 0.6;
    border-radius: 2%;
    border: #ffebcd 2px solid;
}

.section-projects-thumbnail-title-container{
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 90%;
}

.section-projects-thumbnail-title {
    letter-spacing: 0.01rem;
    color: #fafafa;
    font-size: 0.7rem;
    margin-top: 7%;
}


.section-projects-thumbnail-date {
    letter-spacing: 0.02rem;
    margin-top: -4%;
    font-size: 0.6rem;
    color: gray;
}
```

Please let me know how i can fix this.

After trying the suggested solution i'm stuck with this result:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I just found this out recently and have been using it because it has been amazing. First, instead of flex I would do display: grid; and create some grids instead.

```
.index-grid{
    display:grid;
    /* minmax(0, 1fr) lets it all be equal */
    grid-template-columns: minmax(0, 1fr) minmax(0, 1fr) minmax(0, 1fr);
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
  }


add the media query here with the sizes and everything 
 .section-projects-thumbnail-row {
 display: grid;
 /* this is so that there are two columns and everything will overflow from here no matter how many more div element pieces you add */
 grid-template-columns: minmax(0, 1fr) minmax(0, 1fr);
 margin-right: 5%;
 padding-right: 20%;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 position: absolute;
 top: 99%;
 height: 35%;
 width: fit-content;
 /* since this is two columns we wont need the scroll 
 overflow-x: scroll;
 overflow-y: hidden;
 */
 white-space: nowrap;
 box-sizing: border-box;
  }
```

You're HTML would look like this

```
<section class="section-projects-thumbnail-row> 
  <div> <!-- this is your first piece that is being added to the 
  columns --> 
     <img src="this is the img" />
     <p> this is the headline </p>
     <p> this is the caption </p>
  </div>
  <div> <!-- this is your second piece that is being added to the 
  columns --> 
     <img src="this is the img" />
     <p> this is the headline </p>
     <p> this is the caption </p>
  </div>
  <div> <!-- this is your third piece that is being added to the 
  second row of the columns --> 
     <img src="this is the img" />
     <p> this is the headline </p>
     <p> this is the caption </p>
  </div>
  <div> <!-- this is your fourth piece that is being added to the 
  second row of the columns --> 
     <img src="this is the img" />
     <p> this is the headline </p>
     <p> this is the caption </p>
  </div>
```

Basically, now when you run it you will have two columns and no matter how many pieces you have it will add on, then if you want the scroll thing then you make a new meta for a new size and adjust the css accordingly

Comment: Hey thank you, would the `minmax(0, 1fr)` work with a `flex` display?

Comment: @RutvikKarupothula I don't see why it wouldn't but to be honest, using grids makes it much easier especially when you are trying to make a website responsive

Comment: Hey, so I have tried your suggested solution but each time when I try adding new items to the row, all of the projects are visible in the thumbnail. It is not going into the overflow of the `div`.

Comment: @RutvikKarupothula I can't picture what you mean, so each div should have an image and the comment under it, all those divs should be surrounded by one div with a class name, then in the style sheets the class should be listed as i showed in the example... is this sort of what you have going ?

Comment: Yes, that is roughly what I mean, looking at my html code above `.section-projects-thumbnail-row` is the main container, then `section-projects-thumbnail-col` are individual divs. These are updated from my mongoDB. But each time adding new items, it squeezes all of the divs into the viewport, but in my viewport I want to have 2 `cols` and the rest repeat after it and are in overflow. Hope you get what I mean....

Comment: here is a link to the site, if u view it in mobile view (320px) you will see my problem : https://henosisprelaunchview.herokuapp.com/henosis/home

Comment: if you want two columns then the .section-projects-thumbnail-row needs to be grid, like with display:grid; and then grid-template-column: minmax(0, 1fr) minmax(0, 1fr); then when you have this your items (divs) inside the div with class .section-projects-thumbnail-row will automatically fill in and overflow within two columns, you dont need the class .section-prjects-thumbnail-col for the setup unless your adding like different things like specific font or colors etc, im going to edit the original post with a code

Comment: Hey, thanks for that code, I have tried it now, but something still seems wrong. I added a photo to the original question to show how it looks. I need the `section-projects-thumbnail-col` cuz I have specific formatting for those things and its `display: inline-block`. I think now its a problem of sending the extra rows into the `overflow` which is not happening in this case. Sorry to keep bothering you.